# geolocation autocalculate road distance

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I use this script on my site:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script>
    (function () {
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService(),
            directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(),
            createMap = function (start) {
    var travel = {
            origin : (start.coords)? new google.maps.LatLng(start.lat, start.lng) : start.address,
            destination : "Warszawa, al. jerozolimskie 123",
            travelMode : google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
            // Exchanging DRIVING to WALKING above can prove quite amusing :-)
        },
        mapOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            // Default view: downtown Stockholm
            center : new google.maps.LatLng(59.3325215, 18.0643818),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("map-directions"));
    directionsService.route(travel, function(result, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
        }
    });
            };

            // Check for geolocation support    
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            // Success!
            createMap({
                coords : true,
                lat : position.coords.latitude,
                lng : position.coords.longitude
            });
        }, 
        function () {
            // Gelocation fallback: Defaults to Stockholm, Sweden
            createMap({
                coords : false,
                address : "Polska, Warszawa"
            });
        }
    );
            }
            else {
    // No geolocation fallback: Defaults to Lisbon, Portugal
    createMap({
        coords : false,
        address : "Polska, Warszawa"
    });
            }
    })();
</script>
```

I have problem to connect with Haversine formula who calculate road distance between my location and set location...
i dont need any maps or road line on it - only number of km :)

Anybody help my with this?

many thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the APi and found what you want.

Before

> directionsService.route(

Be sure to set:

> unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC

In your **travel** var.

Then after called the route, the Result is a DirectionsResult object. In there, you will have the DirectionRoute array which has an array DirectionsLeg with the distance attribute.

Getting this for your Problem should work as follow:

> var results = result.rows[0].elements;
>
> var distance = results[0].distance.text;

distance.text returns "100 km", where as distance.value would return just "100", whatever you prefer.

Of course it would be better to iterate over these arrays ;) (be sure to implement a check for these, because the distance isn't always filled, the distance can under some circumstances be unknown)

More Information for the API can be found here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions?hl=en

PS: Be sure to use the actual Version V3 of the API, generate your own key and work with it. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial?hl=en#api_key

Comment: i paste "unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC" in  "var travel = {...};, add "var results = result.rows[0].elements;" and "var distance = results[0].distance.text;" on start function... i think i doing something wrong :(

Comment: The results and distance should be inside the route function, because the result var comes from there. I'm not sure if you need V3 of the API for this. Try debugging it using some alert('x'); to see where the problem comes from, (for example if the route returns the OK, if result is filled correctly), I need more information to help

Comment: http://goo.gl/tSZRU   this worked for me! it's a bit different thatn I wrote before

Comment: amaizing... many thanks! Now i see how to do this :) Greate work and many thanks form You for help!